# How to specify cx_Oracle stored function RECORD return type?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, stored-functions

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE my_package as 
       TYPE x_type IS RECORD { a_val number,
                               b_val varchar2(20),
                               c_val boolean }; 
       FUNCTION my_func ( d number )
               RETURN x_type;
```

---

What should be the correct way to specify x_type in cx Oracle code?

```
curs.callfunc('my_func', x_type, [1])
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot,but still can't find how to use type record. As I know ,type record is only supported in pl/sql,so whether can call it in sql would be a question.
I suggest you can use cursor instead of record.
As your reference:

```
create or replace function FN_RETURN_CURS(X NUMBER) return SYS_REFCURSOR is
  C SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin
  OPEN C FOR
    SELECT X, 'A', 1 FROM DUAL;
  return(C);
end FN_RETURN_CURS;
```

In python

```
db=cx_Oracle.connect(...)

>>> cursor=db.cursor()
>>> r=cursor.callfunc('fn_return_curs',cx_Oracle.CURSOR,[5])
>>> r.fetchone()
(5, 'A', 1)
>>>
```

^_^